# error: incompatible types: unexpected return value Char compare to String

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I am trying to compare char to a String but getting an error. 
Error

```
error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
```

code:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = Integer.toBinaryString(2432);
        String p = "0";

        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            return p.equals(new String(new char[]{c}));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the main method has `void` you can't return any thing

Comment: return type of main() is `void` . You can't return any datatype from there

Comment: I think all you need is just `boolean check = s.contains(p);`

Answer (score 5):

The type of `main()` is `void` (`public static` *void* `main(String args[]) {`)
 and therefore you cannot return a value from it.

The actual error I get when I run this is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Void methods cannot return a value
```

Answer (score 2):

Characters are not objects and can / should be compared using the `==` operator. There is no need to build a string each time. Also the `main` method can't return any value, it is `void`.

Comment: I was adding that info.

Answer (score 1):

The main method can not return anything, it has a `void` type. 
You can write a separate function that returns that value, assign the value to a variable, or just print the value.

```
public boolean strChar(String s, String p){
    return p.equals(new String(new char[]{c}));
}
```

or

```
System.out.println(p.equals(new String(new char[]{c})));
```

or

```
boolean equals = p.equals(new String(new char[]{c}));
```